Spring Boot read config value from file
I have the following Spring Boot (3.3.0) config.yaml:
spring:
  datasource:
    appname: ${DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_APPNAME:DocumentIdService}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql:characterEncoding=UTF8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
    username: ${DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD:password}


Instead of password being read from the DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD env var, I would instead like the password to be read by the file pointed to by the env var, for example if DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=/tmp/passwordfile, then that would mean:
password: // Set to content of /tmp/passwordfile, or if /tmp/passwordfile does not exist, default to "mypassword"


I don't think it is possible directly, but there could be a way around to do it. In your start up command, you can first read password from that file and store in a variable, and to the application start up command, you can pass its value.  E.g. DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD=$(cat /tmp/passwordfile) java -jar your-spring-application.jar

The full solution is:
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

public final class SecretPropertyResolver implements EnvironmentPostProcessor
{
    private static final String SECRET_PROPERTY_PREFIX = "secret.";

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(final ConfigurableEnvironment environment, final SpringApplication application)
    {
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertySource<Object>("SecretPropertyResolver")
        {
            @Override
            public Object getProperty(String name)
            {
                // Assuming:
                //   ${secret.MY_PASSWORD:password}
                // This will get called twice:
                //   Once with: secret.MY_PASSWORD:password
                //   Once with: secret.MY_PASSWORD
                // So we need to check for absence of the colon before continuing
                if (name.startsWith(SECRET_PROPERTY_PREFIX) && !name.contains(":")) {
                    final String key = name.substring(SECRET_PROPERTY_PREFIX.length());
                    try {
                        // Logic to read from env/file here
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to read secret '%s'", key), e);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}

src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-factories
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.SecretPropertyResolver

application.yaml
password: ${secret.MY_PASSWORD:password}


We can make use of configtree, this feature(basically reading a folder, map the path of file as configuration name, and file content as value) is likely implemented for your scenario. Assuming you could modify the path of the password file, and you might also want reference other secret in file.
Suppose you have path like
/config/db/password, where password in the file containing your password, e.g "abcde"
And SECRET_CONFIG_FOLDER is the environment variable pointing to /config/db/

import the value using

spring:
  config:
    import: optional:configtree:${SECRET_CONFIG_FOLDER}


Then configuration db.password will be imported with value "abcde", you can reference the value using

spring:
  ...
  datasource:
    password: ${db.password}


To do this, you will have to implement your own EnvironmentPostProcessor in which you will have to read the values ​​of the properties you need.
@Order
public class PropertiesLoader implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    // use environment to read and write properties
  }
}

You must register this postprocessor implementation by specifying the full name of your class in the META-INF/spring.factories file:
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.PropertiesLoader


As long as the following 4 files are the focus of your question, you can ignore the other files.

myPasswordfile
myPasswordfileBBB
application.yaml
DataSourceConfig.java

Project Tree
demo-spring-boot-props-2
├── pom.xml
├── myPasswordfile
├── myPasswordfileBBB
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           ├── model
        │           │   └── Person.java
        │           ├── controller
        │           │   └── PersonController.java
        │           ├── repository
        │           │   └── PersonRepository.java
        │           ├── service
        │           │   └── PersonService.java
        │           ├── DemoJpaApplication.java
        │           ├── WebConfig.java
        │           └── DataSourceConfig.java
        └── resources
            ├── application.yaml
            ├── data.sql
            └── schema.sql

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-boot-props-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-spring-boot-props-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

myPasswordfile
# Wrong Password

AAA=Passw0rd!1233

myPasswordfileBBB
This file is the file specified using the environment variable DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE. The password is placed in the attribute AAA.
# Correct Password

AAA=Passw0rd!

model/Person.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example.model;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String mail;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String mail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}

controller/PersonController.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Person> getAllPersons(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size) {
        return personService.getAllPersons(page, size);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<Person> person = personService.getPersonById(id);
        return personService.getPersonById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return personService.savePerson(person);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Person updatePerson(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Person updatedPerson) {
        Optional<Person> optionalPerson = personService.getPersonById(id);
        if (optionalPerson.isPresent()) {
            Person person = optionalPerson.get();
            person.setName(updatedPerson.getName());
            person.setMail(updatedPerson.getMail());
            return personService.savePerson(person);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deletePerson(@PathVariable Long id) {
        personService.deletePerson(id);
    }
}

repository/PersonRepository.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
}

service/PersonService.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example.service;

import com.example.model.Person;
import com.example.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Page<Person> getAllPersons(int page, int size) {
        return personRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }

    public Optional<Person> getPersonById(Long id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Person savePerson(Person person) {
        return personRepository.save(person);
    }

    public void deletePerson(Long id) {
        personRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

DemoJpaApplication.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

WebConfig.java
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport(pageSerializationMode = EnableSpringDataWebSupport.PageSerializationMode.VIA_DTO)
public class WebConfig {
}

DataSourceConfig.java
Important.
Here we read the attribute AAA from the specified file, turn it into String customPassword, and set it to spring.datasource.password.
package com.example;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
//@PropertySource("classpath:xxxx.properties")
@PropertySource("file:${myPassword.file:NotDefine}")
public class DataSourceConfig {
    // Read custom attribute AAA
    @Value("${AAA}")
    private String customPassword;

    // Set the DataSource and dynamically set the value of AAA to spring.datasource.password
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        System.out.println("customPassword = " + customPassword);
        dataSource.setPassword(customPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }
}

application.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-jpa

  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: demouser
#   password: "Passw0rd!"

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  sql:
    init:
      mode: always

# Swagger
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs

myPassword:
  file: ${DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE:./myPasswordfile}


Note 1: We removed the password field

# password: "Passw0rd!"`


Note 2: We add myPassword.file to set an external password file

myPassword:
 file: ${DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE:./myPasswordfile}`

schema.sql
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (
    ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    MAIL VARCHAR(255)
);

data.sql
You can ignore it and don't need to read the content.
INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, MAIL) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com');
INSERT INTO PERSON (NAME, MAIL) VALUES ('Jane Doe', 'jane@example.com');

Database
Db name : demodb
Db user : demouser
Db password : Passw0rd!
mkdir -p my_pgdata

docker run \
    --name my_postgres_tmp \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=demouser \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Passw0rd! \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=demodb \
    -v `pwd`/my_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -d \
    postgres

Build
mvn clean package

Test
Test 1 - use default - Read password from file : myPasswordfile (wrong password)
$ java -jar target/app.jar

2024-10-02T22:21:36.609+08:00 ERROR 21179 --- [demo-jpa] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "demouser"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication
...

Test 2 - set environment variable DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE
myPasswordfileBBB (correct password)
$ export DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE=myPasswordfileBBB
$ java -jar target/app.jar


create another terminal , read data

$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/persons/1

{"id":1,"name":"John Doe","mail":"john@example.com"}


This works but is a bit clunky.
Step 1: Create a Custom PropertySource
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PasswordFilePropertySource extends PropertySource<String> {

    public PasswordFilePropertySource(String name, String passwordFilePath) {
        super(name, passwordFilePath);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {
        if ("spring.datasource.password".equals(name)) {
            String passwordFilePath = this.getSource();
            try {
                return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(passwordFilePath))).trim();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read password file: " + passwordFilePath, e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Step 2: Register the PropertySource Using an ApplicationContextInitializer
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(YourApplication.class);
        app.addInitializers(new PasswordFileApplicationContextInitializer());
        app.run(args);
    }

    static class PasswordFileApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
            String passwordFilePath = environment.getProperty("DOCUMENT_ID_DATABASE_PASSWORD_FILE", "/default/file");

            PasswordFilePropertySource ps = new PasswordFilePropertySource("passwordFilePropertySource", passwordFilePath);
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
        }
    }
}

Step 3: Keep or Adjust spring.datasource.password in application.yml
You can keep spring.datasource.password in your application.yml for documentation purposes, but it will be overridden by the value from the custom PropertySource.
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb
    username: yourusername
    password: dummyPassword

Note: The value dummyPassword is a placeholder and will be replaced by the password read from the file.

Added logic for @Andrey Smelik solution. don't miss to register the EnvironmentPostProcessor in META-INF/spring.factories
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

public class CustomPropertySourcePostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        String password = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password");

        if (password != null && isValidFilePath(password)) {

            String passwordStr = getFileValue(password);
            passwordStr = passwordStr.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

            if (passwordStr.isEmpty()) {
                passwordStr = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
                writeFileValue(password, passwordStr);
            }

            System.out.println("spring.datasource.password is a valid file path: " + passwordStr);

            Map<String, Object> customProperties = new HashMap<>();
            customProperties.put("spring.datasource.password", passwordStr);

            PropertySource<?> customPropertySource = new MapPropertySource("customPropertySource", customProperties);
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(customPropertySource);
        } else {
            System.out.println("spring.datasource.password is not a valid file path.");
        }
    }

    private boolean isValidFilePath(String filePath) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            return Files.exists(path) && Files.isRegularFile(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String getFileValue(String filePath) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

            return Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void writeFileValue(String filePath, String content) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
            Files.writeString(path, content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


If you want to just configure it with properties file, then use the spring config
#application.yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: "file:${DB_CONFIG_FILE}"

app:
  property1: ${db.password}

Set env variable DB_CONFIG_FILE="<path_to_properties_file_with_extension>
#DB_CONFIG_FILE=dbConfigFile.properties
#database properties
db.password=abc

Note: Spring will use the external file extension and load automatically
